# Python/Kivy : Selection Row in RecycleView using `Up` and `Down` key

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am using python-2.7 and kivy. When i run `test.py` and click on `Test` menu then screen shows like attached image.
1. How to `highlight` first row by default on screen load? When press `up` and `down` key of keyboard then it should be select row according `up` and `down` key .
2. When i click on any row then it opens in `modify` case.How to open selected row in `modify`case using `ctrl+e` instead of click?

## test.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty,NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (600, 325)
from kivy.clock import Clock


class EditStatePopup(Popup):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?"])
    index = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(EditStatePopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.index = obj.index
        self.col_data[0] = obj.rv_data[self.index]["Id"]
        self.col_data[1] = obj.rv_data[self.index]["Name"]



class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    rv_data = ObjectProperty(None)
    start_point = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SelectableButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, .0005)



    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = self.rv_data[self.index][self.key]

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        self.selected = is_selected
        self.rv_data = rv.data



    def on_press(self):
        popup = EditStatePopup(self)
        popup.open()

class MyRV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyRV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self.selectedItem = -1

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        pass

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.clearAll()
            self.nextItem()
            print('down')
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.clearAll()
            self.prevItem()
            print("up")
        elif keycode[1] == 'e' and len(modifiers) > 0 and modifiers[0] == 'ctrl':
            self.view_adapter.views[self.selectedItem].on_press()

    def clearAll(self):
        if (self.selectedItem > -1):
            for i in range(len(self.view_adapter.views) - 1):
                self.view_adapter.views[self.selectedItem].selected = 0


    def nextItem(self):
        if self.selectedItem < len(self.view_adapter.views) - 1:
            self.selectedItem += 1
        else:
            self.selectedItem = 0
        self.view_adapter.views[self.selectedItem].selected = 1
        print(self.selectedItem)


    def prevItem(self):
        if self.selectedItem > 0:
            self.selectedItem -= 1
        else:
            self.selectedItem = len(self.view_adapter.views) - 1
        self.view_adapter.views[self.selectedItem].selected = 1
        print(self.selectedItem)



class RV(RecycleView):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    col1 = ListProperty()
    col2 = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_states()

    def update(self):
        self.col1 = [{'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Id', 'text': str(x[2])} for x in self.data_items]
        self.col2 = [{'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Name', 'text': str(x[2])} for x in self.data_items]


    def get_states(self):
        rows = [(1, 'Test1'), (2, 'Test2'), (3, 'Test3')]

        i = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.data_items.append([row[0], row[1], i])
            i += 1
        print(self.data_items)
        self.update()



class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    states_cities_or_areas = ObjectProperty()

    def display_states(self):
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.rv = RV()
        self.states_cities_or_areas.add_widget(self.rv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        self.states_cities_or_areas.clear_widgets()

class TestApp(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<SelectableButton>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (10, 10, 10, 10) if self.selected else (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<MyRV@RecycleView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
    SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        default_size: None, dp(26)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .1
                text: "Id"
            Label:
                size_hint_x: .5
                text: "Name"

        BoxLayout:
            MyRV:
                size_hint_x: .1
                data: root.col1
            MyRV:
                size_hint_x: .5
                data: root.col2



<EditStatePopup>:
    size_hint: None, None
    title_size: 20
    title_font: "Verdana"
    size: 400, 275
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            #backgroun_color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
            spacing: 10, 10
            padding: 20, 20
            Label:
                text: "Id"
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text: root.col_data[0]
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text: "Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                focus : True
                text: root.col_data[1]
                text_size: self.size

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 10, 0, 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: .5, .2
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.65}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'


            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                size_hint_x: .5
                on_release: root.dismiss()




<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (80,30)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)


<MainMenu>:
    states_cities_or_areas: states_cities_or_areas


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        #spacing : 10

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 1

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Test'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: root.display_states()


        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

                Color:
                    rgb: (1,1,1)

            Label:
                size_hint_x: 45

        BoxLayout:
            id: states_cities_or_areas
            size_hint_y: 10

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a few methods in the class *SelectableRecycleGridLayout* to make use of methods in the class *[LayoutSelectionBehavior](https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/uix/recycleview/layout.html)*. Please refer to the test plans, concerns, example, and output for details.

## Concerns

There are two concerns regarding the original program that will impact performance and memory usage.

### Issue 1

Calling method *update* to set the widget's text every 0.0005 seconds. This is very expensive. Please refer to [Programming Guide » Events and Properties » Scheduling a repetitive event & Trigger events](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html).

```
class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ...
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SelectableButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, .0005)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = self.rv_data[self.index][self.key]
```

### Solution - Issue 1

Added *text* in the method *update* of class *RV*.

```
class RV(BoxLayout):
    ...
    def update(self):
        self.col1_data = [{'text': str(x[0]), 'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Id', 'selectable': True}
                          for x in self.data_items]

        self.col2_data = [{'text': x[1], 'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Name', 'selectable': True}
                          for x in self.data_items]
```

### Issue 2

*col1_data* and *col2_data* are similar except the text and dictonary for *key* (*Id* or *Name*). When the ***data grows bigger***, the app might not run because it ran out of memory, and if it does run, it gives poor performance.

### Solution - Issue 2

No solution provided because it is out of this topic and  left as an exercise for you.

## Test Plans

1. Clicked Test, RecycleView displayed and first row highlighted.
2. Press down arrow key, next row highlighted.
3. At last row, press down arrow key, the first row highligthed.
4. Press up arrow key, previous row hightlighted.
5. At first row, press up arrow key, last row highlighted.
6. Press Ctrl + e, Popup window display informations of highlighted row.
7. Mouse click on any row that is not highlighted, the mouse clicked row is selected, and Popup window open.
8. Mouse clicked on any row, after Popup dismissed, keyboard events still works!

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, DictProperty

from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (600, 325)


class EditStatePopup(Popup):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?"])

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(EditStatePopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.col_data[0] = obj["Id"]
        self.col_data[1] = obj["Name"]


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

    selected_row = NumericProperty(0)

    def get_nodes(self):
        nodes = self.get_selectable_nodes()
        if self.nodes_order_reversed:
            nodes = nodes[::-1]
        if not nodes:
            return None, None

        selected = self.selected_nodes
        if not selected:    # nothing selected, select the first
            self.select_node(nodes[0])
            self.selected_row = 0
            return None, None

        if len(nodes) == 1:     # the only selectable node is selected already
            return None, None

        last = nodes.index(selected[-1])
        self.clear_selection()
        return last, nodes

    def select_next(self):
        ''' Select next row '''
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        if last == len(nodes) - 1:
            self.select_node(nodes[0])
            self.selected_row = nodes[0]
        else:
            self.select_node(nodes[last + 1])
            self.selected_row = nodes[last + 1]

    def select_previous(self):
        ''' Select previous row '''
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        if not last:
            self.select_node(nodes[-1])
            self.selected_row = nodes[-1]
        else:
            self.select_node(nodes[last - 1])
            self.selected_row = nodes[last - 1]

    def select_current(self):
        ''' Select current row '''
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        self.select_node(nodes[self.selected_row])


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''

        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            print("on_touch_down: self=", self)
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected


class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    row_data = DictProperty({})
    col1_data = ListProperty([])
    col2_data = ListProperty([])
    col1_row_controller = ObjectProperty(None)
    col2_row_controller = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_states()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_default_first_row, .0005)
        self._request_keyboard()

    def _request_keyboard(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text'
        )
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            # If it exists, this widget is a VKeyboard object which you can use
            # to change the keyboard layout.
            pass
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'down':    # keycode[274, 'down'] pressed
            # Respond to keyboard down arrow pressed
            self.display_keystrokes(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
            self.col1_row_controller.select_next()
            self.col2_row_controller.select_next()

        elif keycode[1] == 'up':    # keycode[273, 'up] pressed
            # Respond to keyboard up arrow pressed
            self.display_keystrokes(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
            self.col1_row_controller.select_previous()
            self.col2_row_controller.select_previous()

        elif len(modifiers) > 0 and modifiers[0] == 'ctrl' and text == 'e':     # ctrl + e pressed
            # Respond to keyboard ctrl + e pressed, and call Popup
            self.display_keystrokes(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
            keyboard.release()
            self.on_keyboard_select()

        # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()

        # Return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by
        # the system.
        return True

    def display_keystrokes(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print("\nThe key", keycode, "have been pressed")
        print(" - text is %r" % text)
        print(" - modifiers are %r" % modifiers)

    def on_keyboard_select(self):
        ''' Respond to keyboard event to call Popup '''

        # setup row data for Popup
        self.row_data = self.col1_data[self.col1_row_controller.selected_row]

        # call Popup
        self.popup_callback()

    def on_mouse_select(self, instance):
        ''' Respond to mouse event to call Popup '''

        if (self.col1_row_controller.selected_row != instance.index
                or self.col2_row_controller.selected_row != instance.index):
            # Mouse clicked on row is not equal to current selected row
            self.col1_row_controller.selected_row = instance.index
            self.col2_row_controller.selected_row = instance.index

            # Hightlight mouse clicked/selected row
            self.col1_row_controller.select_current()
            self.col2_row_controller.select_current()

        # setup row data for Popup
        # we can use either col1_data or col2_data because they are duplicate and each stores the same info
        self.row_data = self.col1_data[instance.index]

        # call Popup
        self.popup_callback()

    def popup_callback(self):
        ''' Instantiate and Open Popup '''
        popup = EditStatePopup(self.row_data)
        popup.open()

        # enable keyboard request
        self._request_keyboard()

    def set_default_first_row(self, dt):
        ''' Set default first row as selected '''
        self.col1_row_controller.select_next()
        self.col2_row_controller.select_next()

    def update(self):
        self.col1_data = [{'text': str(x[0]), 'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Id', 'selectable': True}
                          for x in self.data_items]

        self.col2_data = [{'text': x[1], 'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Name', 'selectable': True}
                          for x in self.data_items]

    def get_states(self):
        rows = [(1, 'Test1'), (2, 'Test2'), (3, 'Test3')]

        i = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.data_items.append([row[0], row[1], i])
            i += 1
        print(self.data_items)
        self.update()


class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    states_cities_or_areas = ObjectProperty(None)
    rv = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_states(self):
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.rv = RV()
        self.states_cities_or_areas.add_widget(self.rv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        self.states_cities_or_areas.clear_widgets()


class TestApp(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<EditStatePopup>:
    size_hint: None, None
    title_size: 20
    title_font: "Verdana"
    size: 400, 275
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            #background_color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
            spacing: 10, 10
            padding: 20, 20
            Label:
                text: "Id"
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text: root.col_data[0]
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text: "Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                text: root.col_data[1]
                text_size: self.size
                focus: True
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                size_hint: 1, 0.4
                text: "Save Changes"
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss()
            Button:
                size_hint: 1, 0.4
                text: "Cancel Changes"
                on_release: root.dismiss()


<SelectableButton>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1) if self.selected else (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    background_color: [1, 0, 0, 1]  if self.selected else [1, 1, 1, 1]  # dark red else dark grey
    on_press: app.root.rv.on_mouse_select(self)


<RV>:
    col1_row_controller: col1_row_controller
    col2_row_controller: col2_row_controller

    orientation: "vertical"

    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 25
        cols: 3

        Label:
            size_hint_x: .1
            text: "Id"
        Label:
            size_hint_x: .5
            text: "Name"

    BoxLayout:
        RecycleView:
            size_hint_x: .1
            data: root.col1_data
            viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
            SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                id: col1_row_controller
                key_selection: 'selectable'
                cols: 1
                default_size: None, dp(26)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                multiselect: True
                touch_multiselect: True

        RecycleView:
            size_hint_x: .5
            data: root.col2_data
            viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
            SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                id: col2_row_controller
                key_selection: 'selectable'
                cols: 1
                default_size: None, dp(26)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                multiselect: True
                touch_multiselect: True


<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (80,30)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)


<MainMenu>:
    states_cities_or_areas: states_cities_or_areas

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        #spacing : 10

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 1

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Test'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: root.display_states()


        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

                Color:
                    rgb: (1,1,1)

            Label:
                size_hint_x: 45

        BoxLayout:
            id: states_cities_or_areas
            size_hint_y: 10

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 1
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - RV displayed after clicked Test]
[image: Img03 - Ctrl+e at first row]
[image: Img04 - Down Arrow key pressed]
[image: Img05 - Up Arrow key pressed]
[image: Img06 - Ctrl+e pressed]
[image: Img07 - Mouse click on first row]

Comment: Thanks. But when i set `focus : True` in `TextInput` after then pressed `ctrl+e` after click on `cancel changes` after `up` and `down` key does not move up and down.

Comment: I have updated my post. In *test.kv*, added *focus: True* to the *TextInput* in the *Popup*. In *main.py*, moved the call  to *self._request_keyboard()* from method *on_mouse_select(self, instance)* and *append* it to method *popup_callback(self)*.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use 2 different colors on the SelectableButton
2. Check for keypress and trigger on_press

text.kv

```
<SelectableButton>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1) if self.selected else (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<MyRV@RecycleView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
    SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        default_size: None, dp(26)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .1
                text: "Id"
            Label:
                size_hint_x: .5
                text: "Name"

        BoxLayout:
            MyRV:
                size_hint_x: .1
                data: root.col1
            MyRV:
                size_hint_x: .5
                data: root.col2


<EditStatePopup>:
    size_hint: None, None
    title_size: 20
    title_font: "Verdana"
    size: 400, 275
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            #backgroun_color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
            spacing: 10, 10
            padding: 20, 20
            Label:
                text: "Id"
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text: root.col_data[0]
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text: "Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                text: root.col_data[1]
                text_size: self.size



<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (80,30)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)


<MainMenu>:
    states_cities_or_areas: states_cities_or_areas


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        #spacing : 10

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 1

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Test'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: root.display_states()


        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

                Color:
                    rgb: (1,1,1)

            Label:
                size_hint_x: 45

        BoxLayout:
            id: states_cities_or_areas
            size_hint_y: 10

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 1
```

TestApp.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty,NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (600, 325)
from kivy.clock import Clock


class EditStatePopup(Popup):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?"])
    index = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(EditStatePopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.index = obj.index
        self.col_data[0] = obj.rv_data[self.index]["Id"]
        self.col_data[1] = obj.rv_data[self.index]["Name"]



class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    rv_data = ObjectProperty(None)
    start_point = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SelectableButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, .0005)



    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = self.rv_data[self.index][self.key]

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        self.selected = is_selected
        self.rv_data = rv.data



    def on_press(self):
        popup = EditStatePopup(self)
        popup.open()

class MyRV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyRV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self.selectedItem = -1

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        pass

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.clearAll()
            self.nextItem()
            print('down')
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.clearAll()
            self.prevItem()
            print("up")
        elif keycode[1] == 'e' and len(modifiers) > 0 and modifiers[0] == 'ctrl':
            self.view_adapter.views[self.selectedItem].on_press()

    def clearAll(self):
        if (self.selectedItem > -1):
            for i in range(len(self.view_adapter.views) - 1):
                self.view_adapter.views[self.selectedItem].selected = 0


    def nextItem(self):
        if self.selectedItem < len(self.view_adapter.views) - 1:
            self.selectedItem += 1
        else:
            self.selectedItem = 0
        self.view_adapter.views[self.selectedItem].selected = 1
        print(self.selectedItem)


    def prevItem(self):
        if self.selectedItem > 0:
            self.selectedItem -= 1
        else:
            self.selectedItem = len(self.view_adapter.views) - 1
        self.view_adapter.views[self.selectedItem].selected = 1
        print(self.selectedItem)



class RV(RecycleView):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    col1 = ListProperty()
    col2 = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_states()

    def update(self):
        self.col1 = [{'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Id', 'text': str(x[2])} for x in self.data_items]
        self.col2 = [{'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Name', 'text': str(x[2])} for x in self.data_items]


    def get_states(self):
        rows = [(1, 'Test1'), (2, 'Test2'), (3, 'Test3')]

        i = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.data_items.append([row[0], row[1], i])
            i += 1
        print(self.data_items)
        self.update()



class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    states_cities_or_areas = ObjectProperty()

    def display_states(self):
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.rv = RV()
        self.states_cities_or_areas.add_widget(self.rv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        self.states_cities_or_areas.clear_widgets()

class TestApp(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: thanks for help. Can you give me one more favour when i pressed `ctrl+e` then 2 popup open.How to open only one `popup` for edit ?

Comment: i changed self.selectedItem = -1 to self.selectedItem = 0 But first row not showing selected when all `rows` load